# css background image gets cut in mobile landscape mode

Tags: css, background-image, landscape-portrait

I'm building
 [this landing page](http://ari.seveloff.com/) 
in mobile landscape mode the background image gets cut right at the scrolling point.

how can i fix it so i will see the entire image while scrolling the page?
tnx

Comment: your site is not responsive so which resolution you are talking about? please provide fix resolution where you want your solution

Comment: for this resolution: max-width: 1080px

Comment: if you had a responsive width property you could use `background-size:contain` to avoid cutting off

Answer (score 0):

You can use srcset attribute which targets different resolution.
If you want to target your application in all types of devices (large to small), it is not wise to use the same image targeting all resolutions.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/extralarge.jpg, img/extralarge.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
  <source srcset="img/large.jpg, img/large.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <source srcset="img/medium.jpg">
  <img srcset="img/medium.jpg" alt="Sample Test">
</picture>
```

In the code above, I have used 3 different types of images targeting different resolutions.

In addition, you can use responsive images
Check the url
http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice